# get results returned in a function

Tags: php

i have this inside a php function:

```
$result = new stdClass();
$result->domainname = $domainName;
$result->element = $element;
$result->availability = $availability;

return ($result);
```

so its returning all of the values in the `$result` variable

when i do a `print_r` on the function, the results display like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [domainname] => domain.com
    [element] => 
    [availability] => false
)
```

i am calling the function with this code:

```
$domain = domainNameCheck($_GET["domain"].'.'.$_GET["tld"]);
```

so i tried to get the returned by doing `$domain->availability` but its not returning the value, example:

```
if($domain->availability) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

am i trying to get the data the incorrect way?

**UPDATE**

the full function is:

```
if(!function_exists("domainNameCheck")) {
    function domainNameCheck($domainName, $element) {
        $result = '';

        $client = new IcukApiClient();
        $client->username = "username";
        $client->key = "pass";
        $client->encryption = "SHA-512";

        $req = new IcukApiRequest();
        $req->url = "/domain/availability/" . $domainName;
        $req->method = "GET";

        $res = $client->send($req);
        $availability = 'unknown';
        if ($res->success) {
            $obj = json_decode($res->response);
            $availability =($obj->available) ? 'true' : 'false';
        }
        else {
            $availability = 'unknown';
        }

        $result = new stdClass();
        $result->domainname = $domainName;
        $result->element = $element;
        $result->availability = $availability;

        return ($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific and give some example of code which does not work properly ?

Comment: That should work so show all the function code as something else must have gone wrong

Comment: Please be aware that if you do `echo $domain->availability;` and its value is `false` like you say it is, then you'll have no output. `false` converted to string is the empty string.

Comment: Try this `echo $domain->availability ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';`

Comment: We can guess as much as we like, we cannot provide a decent answer without more details...

Comment: I don't get it really.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The question, it was. Actually was confused between the code inside `domainNameCheck()` function. Seeing answer below make it clear now.

Comment: *"but its not returning the value, example"*: the example you give is a piece of code, not the output you get and how it is different from expectations. Can you clarify?

Comment: You are calling a function with 2 required parameters, but passing only one parameter. That should throw a compile error

Comment: when using `if($domain->availability) {` its always returning `true`, meaning `availability` is always true although its telling me its false in the `print_r`

Comment: strings are always true unless they are empty. So `if ("false") ` will be considered true by the `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be that you are calling a function with 2 parameters but passing only one parameter

```
function domainNameCheck($domainName, $element) {}

// called like this (one parameter)
$domain = domainNameCheck($_GET["domain"].'.'.$_GET["tld"]);
```

This should be generating a compile error!

Also here

```
if ($res->success) {
    $obj = json_decode($res->response);

    // check what $obj->available is set to
    // it may also be a string and not a boolean

    print_r($obj);

    $availability =($obj->available) ? 'true' : 'false';
}
else {
    $availability = 'unknown';
}
```

Comment: ive already tried and its returning true all the time even thought the `print_r` result shows false

Comment: I see you are setting `availability` to a string `true or `false` so I removed the part about echo not working

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there are two error/warning messages PHP is giving:

> E_WARNING : type 2 -- Missing argument 2 for domainNameCheck()
>
> E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: element

You should fix those errors, and make sure you are [informed of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) during development.

Secondly, you have defined your availability as a string by assigning `"false"`, `"true"`, or `"unknown"`. So when you do this:

```
if($domain->availability) {
```

... that will be true for all three values, because strings are true for PHP when converted to boolean (except when empty). To illustrate, this will `echo` "hello":

```
if ("false") echo "hello";
```

So you need to change your test like this:

```
if($domain->availability === "true") {
```

Or, If you want to define `$domain->availability` as a true boolean, then you need to alter the assignments in your function, like this:

```
        ....
        $availability = $obj->available; // assuming that is a boolean!
    }
    else {
        $availability = null; // unknown
    }
```

... and then you can do what you had:

```
if($domain->availability) {
```

Comment: Seems a little over kill to have to run a `json_encode()` just to display true or false

Comment: It's just a way of showing what is in the variable, which will work with whatever value it has, boolean, string, number, ... whatever.

Comment: check my comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Likely because $domain->availability is [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

To output you can first check whether its true or false and output accordingly

here's a simple example:

```
if ($domain->availability){
    echo 'Available';
}
else {
    echo 'Not Available';
}
```